# How can I find this limit applying squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I evaluate this limit applying squeeze theorem?

> $$\lim_{x\to6}\frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}}}{x-6}$$

I found this limit with standart way:

> $\lim_{x\to6}\frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}}}{x-6}=\lim_{x\to6}\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}} \right)\times \left( 1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}}\right)}{(x-6)\times \left( 1+\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}}\right)}=\frac 18$

I want to write this limit using squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

First step let wlog $y=x-6\to 0^+$ thus

$$\lim_{x\to6^+}\frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{x-2}}}{x-6}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}}{y}$$

then by Bernoulli inequality

$$\sqrt{y+4} =2(1+y/4)^\frac12\le 2(1+y/8)=2+y/4$$

$$3-\sqrt{y+4}\ge 3-2-y/4=1-y/4$$

$$\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}\ge \sqrt{ 1-y/4}$$

$$1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}\le 1-\sqrt{ 1-y/4}$$

then

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}}{y} \le \frac{1-\sqrt{ 1-y/4}}{y}$$

For the other inequality use that

$$\sqrt{y+4} =2(1+y/4)^\frac12\ge 2(1+y/8-y^2/128)=2+y/4-y^2/64$$

$$3-\sqrt{y+4}\le 3-2-y/4+y^2/64$$

$$\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}\le \sqrt{ 1-y/4+y^2/64}$$

$$1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}\ge 1-\sqrt{ 1-y/4+y^2/64}$$

Then finally

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{ 1-y/4+y^2/64}}{y} \le \frac{1-\sqrt{ 3-\sqrt{y+4}}}{y} \le  \frac{1-\sqrt{ 1-y/4}}{y}$$

Comment: and let $y=0$ but this doesnt work?

Comment: @Elementary $y\to 0^+$ and certainly it doesn't make sense to $y=0$.

Comment: can you show final step?

Comment: @Elementary As Sebastiano noted $y=0$ doesn't make sense. It could be useful if you check all the step instead to be sure all is ok. We are using that for $t\to 0^+$ $$1+t/2-t^2/8 \le (1+t)^{\frac12}\le 1+t/2$$

Comment: Sorry I can not see where $\frac 18$ comes from

Comment: @Elementary You can conclude using for RHS and LHS by $(1+t)^\frac12\sim t/2$ or $$\frac{1-\sqrt {f(y)}}{y}=\frac{1-\sqrt {f(y)}}{y}\frac{1+\sqrt {f(y)}}{1+\sqrt {f(y)}}$$

Comment: Okay. In fact, we used the same method as I did.

Comment: @Elementary Indeed, in that case squeeze theorem doesn't seem the best metod in that case!

Comment: I understood you.